# Insert an HTML tag at the beginning and end of a user's selection in a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contentEditable div in which I want users to be able to press a button and make the text they have selected bold. The way that I am doing it now uses `window.getSelection.toString();` to get the text in the selection, and replace that with a bold element that has the same contents, but `window.getSelection.toString()` does not include any HTML elements inside the selection.

To get around this, I want to add HTML tags to the beginning and end of the selection. I've found other answers on stack overflow for adding HTML to the beginning and end of a selection, but those append a div or span to the beginning and end, resulting in
`<div><b></div> Selection text <div></b></div>` isolating the bold tags from the actual selection text.

I am not using any libraries and would prefer not to have to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to get (or change) the HTML contents using window.getSelection and Range API, and now it is recommended way, and also now a wider support that time ago it didn't: https://caniuse.com/#feat=selection-api

First the get html example:

```js
function butclick() {
  var ediv = document.getElementById('your-editable-div'); // get a reference to the editable div
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); // get the range
  var aux = document.createElement("span"); // create an auxiliar tag
  aux.appendChild(range.cloneContents()); // clone (so the original selection is not removed or replaced) and insert it into the auxiliar dom tag
  alert(aux.innerHTML); // now you can get the innerHTML of the aux tag
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable id="your-editable-div" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px; margin: 5px;">This is <b>an editable</b> div with html tags</div>
<button onclick="butclick()">get html of selected area</button>
```

And here how to change that html into other html:

```js
function butclick() {
  var ediv = document.getElementById('your-editable-div'); // get a reference to the div
  ediv.focus(); // optional: focus again the editable div so you can continue editting
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); // select first of the selections
  var aux = document.createElement("span"); // create an aux html span tag
  aux.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // apply some new style
  aux.appendChild(range.extractContents()); // extract (so the original contents are removed) and inyect into aux tag
  range.insertNode(aux); // finally insert back again the edited aux node back into the editable div, this includes the aux tag itself, but you can insert whatever dom tag you want, or various tags, or even only the children
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable id="your-editable-div" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px; margin: 5px;">This is <b>an editable</b> div with html tags</div>
<button onclick="butclick()">replace html with other html</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.execCommand()`. It's obsolete and [MDN says it shouldn't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), but almost every library *(ex: [MediumEditor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/src/js/core.js#L47), [Editor.js](https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/blob/master/src/components/inline-tools/inline-tool-bold.ts#L73), and even [Google Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryxQn.jpg))* is using it, so you can believe it will get a lot of support from the community.

```js
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', makeBold);
document.getElementById('ital').addEventListener('click', makeItalic);

function makeBold() { document.execCommand('bold'); }
function makeItalic() { document.execCommand('italic'); }
```

```css
#content { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #f1f1f1; padding: .5em .2em; margin: .5em 0; }
```

```html
<button id="bold"><b>Bold</b></button>
<button id="ital"><i>Italic</i></button>

<div id="content" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```